# how to find data for whole month for date format dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a database with date format "yyyyymmdd' and data-type varchar(8). In this case when I need to find a data for whole month I used to write code like below :

```
  select * from table1
  where Date Between (convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112)+'01')
  AND (convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112)+'31'))
```

Now I just have a new table with date format "dd/mm/yyyy" and date type varchar(10) and I would like to  extract data from the table for whole month without specifying exact date. I want start date as first day of current and month and end date as last day of the current month.

But I don't now how to do the same as the date format is now 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

Comment: Why is your date stored as a varchar? I suggest you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, thing you should store you date as the datatype of `date` and not `varchar`

You can use [`MONTH()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE MONTH(convert(datetime, dt, 103)) = MONTH(getdate()) -- or month you want
```

or [`DATEPART()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DatePart(month, convert(datetime, dt, 103)) = DatePart(month, getdate())
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1e1a/2)

Both of these, get the value of the `MONTH()` -- 8, 9, 10 -- and then compares it to the month that you want.

Comment: thanks blueffeet .... it works perfect..but I wonder if it can also be  written in the similar way I have written for format 'yyyymmdd' in the original question.

Comment: @user1449596 you still should be able to use it for dates in the format `yyyymmdd`

Comment: Note that applying month and datepart to the column will mean that an index can't be used (not that an index on d/m/y would be very useful at all). But if the data type gets fixed it will be much better to say >= {month} and < {month + 1}.

Comment: Thanks bluefeet..will i need to change the code for next year?
@Aaron Bertrand..I will try to change data type as soon as possible. Thank you too.

Comment: @user1449596 the `getdate()` will always have today's date so that will not have to change

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50efd/7)**

**[DEMO 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05bc3/1)**

Sample
 `select idcol,namecol,datecol, from table where  datepart(mm,datecol)='9'`

**Edit:**

`select * from dummy where datepart(mm,dob)= datepart(mm,getdate())`
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50efd/7

Their is posibility of same month with different year so you also you need to takecare of year some like by adding `and  datepart(yyyy,dob)=datepart(yyyy,getdate())`

Comment: @satinder..in this case...I will need to manually specify month every month. I have an update store procedure and I want it to update on executing for whole month automatically without specifying month name.